# Is the AUC a robust metric to determine which network architecture to use?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, roc, auc

I would like to figure out which hyperparameters/network architectures work best on a specific binary dataset.  To compare them, I do k-fold cross-validation, use different MLP or ConvNet architectures and tune hyperparameters for both. For each, I compute the ROC-curves and am supposing that the iterations with higher AUC (area under curve) are necessarily better.  Is this justifiable?

Comment: This is 100% justifiable in ML.

Comment: thanks, are there other metrics worth exploring as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is standard practice: run a lot of experiments, pick the one with the highest score on the hold-out. The caveats here are straightforward: The AUC is a statistic, and like every other statistic it is subject to random variation, so picking the highest AUC value might be slightly worse in reality than another hyper-parameter configuration by chance. But this is the nature of living with randomness.

You might be interested in this answer, which indirectly addresses how one might efficiently search for a good hyper-parameter configuration:
[Optimization when Cost Function Slow to Evaluate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193306/optimization-when-cost-function-slow-to-evaluate/193310#193310)

You could also carry out a statistical test to compare whether one ROC curve is significantly better than another. See: [Statistical significance (p-value) for comparing two classifiers with respect to (mean) ROC AUC, sensitivity and specificity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358101/statistical-significance-p-value-for-comparing-two-classifiers-with-respect-to)

There are all sorts of other metrics that people use to measure model performance. Some of them are:

- log loss/cross-entropy
- Brier score
- TPR at a specific FPR
- Area under the precision-recall curve

Generally, you might be interested in [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules).