# Transformer model training takes longer and results in lower train and validation loss

Tags: neural-networks, keras, recurrent-neural-network, transformers

I have been making tests with Transformer model provided on [Keras.io page](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_with_transformer/), training for classification and seq2seq tasks in several datasets and compare Transformer to GRU/LSTM with almost same number of parameters in both models.

In all my experiments, everything but the model are controlled variable and they are constant.
I conducted my tests with GPU on my desktop (GTX 1070), Google Colab GPU and AWS Tesla T4.

What I witnessed are:

- Training Transformer model takes longer for same number of epochs
- Both training and validation loss are much higher for Transformer model, than GRU/LSTM model at the end of same number of epochs.

I tried various number of "number_of_heads" and "number_of_transformer_blocks", result did not change really.

Transformers were said to be superior to RNNs like GRU/LSTM but I have never witnessed that. Therefore my question is, am I missing something?

Comment: Are you tuning the hyperparameters of the models? Which ones? How?

Comment: I am not tuning hyperparameters, I use same parameters whenever possible such as optimizer (adam), learning rate, embedding size. Such a huge gap for vanilla models doesn't sound right. I can provide a comparison Notebook on Colab soon.

Comment: Tune the hyperparameters, especially the learning rate. The question you're implicitly trying to answer is "how does the best transformer network compare to the best LSTM/GRU network?" and the only way to get the best version of a network is to tune it.

Comment: What you describe is not superiority. I can get a tuned MLP against RNN for a sequence model that does better than RNN for a task and data but that would not mean to advertise MLP as "superior."  Having said that, I am open to advices of tuning.

Comment: You're saying that one network being better than an alternative, comparably-sized network is not a demonstration that one is "superior" to the other? What does "superior" mean to you? // Anyway, there's plenty of material about tuning neural networks that you can find using a search. Here's one example to get you started. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342462/hyperparameter-tuning-in-neural-networks

Comment: I am facing the same here, I also read about it in a scientific paper although the dataset is medium size. I notice that (the RMSprop optimizer) outperforms Adam, at least in my case for time series classification. Also, I noticed that they need more epochs to reach a good result compared to other models.
I read about using a cyclical learning rate, but I did not try it yet .