# Using a surrogate model for the solution space of an optimization problem

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, references, random-forest, complex-numbers

I have an optimization problem: Given a complex $n\times n$ covariance matrix $C$ one must find a complex $n$-vector $v_C^\ast$ which (approximately) minimizes an objective $f_C(v)$ over all space.  $n$ is around 5 or so.

The ultimate goal is to design a procedure which quickly translates covariance matrices $C$ into a near-optimal vector.

$C$ and $f_C$ are known "at runtime" and $f_C$ is readily computable, but the optimization problem is hard. $f_C$ has many close-to-optimal local maxima and discontinuities. The most efficient technique known to directly find $v_C^\ast$ is by random trials: choose components randomly uniform over a box at the origin.  This is slow and naive, but performs consistently well.

Because we only need an approximate solution, I am hoping that learning techniques can help. My idea is to spend a long time building a large dictionary of known-good pairs $(C,v_C^\ast)$, then training a model on the dictionary. What learning techniques might be suited for this purpose?

---

My first idea is to use random forest regression, except instead of averaging from the committee of trees, just choose the best of them instead. Does this have a chance of working?

Comment: Search (this site and web) for " surrogate models"

Comment: Superb, had never heard of this term before. Thanks!

Comment: The suggestions at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193306/optimization-when-cost-function-slow-to-evaluate/193310#193310 seem relevant.