# Optimizing a single parameter. Best practices?

Tags: optimization

I've been recently working with an optimization problem, where I have to optimize a single parameter. I cannot test all parameter values, as the process is too expensive.

My function(s) look like this:[image]

Please ignore the x axis after value of 50, as this is a bug. So, find a maximum of the given function -- that is the task.

Currently, I am doing a linear search across all parameter range, yet this is expensive.

Comment: Related question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193306/optimization-when-cost-function-slow-to-evaluate?rq=1

Comment: What information do you have about the function(s)? Are they black-box functions or not?

Comment: It is a black box function yes.