# Can neural networks learn many to one function?

Tags: neural-networks, hyperparameter

I am thinking of building a secondary Neural Net to train the relation between the hyper-parameters and test set accuracy of my primary Neural Net, so as to maximize it efficiently.

And there are 2 ways to approach this:

1). Let the input features be the hyper-parameters(X) and output be the test acc(Y). Then after the network has learned, I can provide the value of test acc and obtain the optimum hyperparams by applying inverted weights and activation functions on Y.

But i realized that the relation between X->Y is many to one. Different set of X could give the same value of Y. So is the above method even possible.

2. If the above method isnt possible, then is it plausible to train my NN with X as test acc and Y as the hyperparams and hope it would work?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you: if you have binary classification problem, than you also have a map of different values, to only two possible values.

Comment: @Tim - indeed all classifications and most regressions with more than one independent variables are many-to-one

Comment: suppose input features x1 and x2 .and output y. suppose the actual mathematical relation is y= x1*x2. And i can train my neural network to learn that relation. But after the network has learned and i try to obtain the value of x1 and x2 for y=12. by inverting the forward prop, what will i get 4,3 or 6,2 or 12,1 or something else or some error?? that is the question

Comment: One equation with two unknown values and no further information isn't solvable. Neural networks aren't magic.

Comment: Ah yes you're right. So is there any other way to  automate the hyperparamter optimization proces?

Comment: There are lots. Some examples: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193306/optimization-when-cost-function-slow-to-evaluate/193310#193310