# How to Efficiently Finding All Local Maxima in a Large Parameter Space

Tags: gradient-descent, gradient

I am working in 8-D parameter space, where every parameter is on the interval [0, 1]. The number of local maxima in this space and how they are positioned relative to one another is **way** more interesting than the exact value of the global maxima. Since gradient ascent algorithms can actually miss global maxima because they get stuck at local maxima, I thought I could use their biggest 'flaw' to my advantage.

My plan was to pick 50,000 or so points evenly spaced throughout my parameter space and run a GA program with each as the initial guess. The problem I have is that calculating the gradient at a single point is computationally taxing, so running this many GA programs is not feasible on my computer. The only solution I can think of is to use even less initial points, but then the chances of me missing a local maxima is even greater. Is there some other way to go about this that I am not thinking of?

Comment: You can always use derivate-free methods, if this is an issue.

Comment: Some suggestions about optimization of expensive functions are here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193306/optimization-when-cost-function-slow-to-evaluate but are primarily oriented around finding the best optimum, not all optima.