# How to find the maximum point given two predictor variables

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, optimization

I have 3 variables where 2 are predictors (positive integers) and the response variable is a real number.

To give an example:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 | 7 |

Because this dataset is unique to my problem, I don't have an equation that can explain the relationship among `a, b, c`.

However, when I plot these as a surface, there is a nonlinear relationship.

How do I go about to find the maximum value of `c` while minimizing `a, b`. I know this sounds like a numerical optimization problem but without an equation, I won't be able to solve it.

Edit: can machine learning help here? Large amount of data can be obtained.

Comment: You'll need some kind of equation to express exactly what you want to optimize. Suppose you have {A, B, C} = {0, 0, 10}. Is that preferable to {1, 1, 50}, which maximizes C but fails to minimize A and B? What about {0, 10, 100}? We have no way of knowing which is "best". This is an optimization problem, but you can't solve it without defining what to optimize.

Comment: Will I need one equation to tie ```a, c``` together and another one for ```b, c```, or is it one equation for all the variables? How can I generate these equations?

Comment: Are you asking about creating a surrogate surface of `c` in terms of `a,b`? Because that's easily done using e.g. Gaussian processes; here's a bibliography https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/207025/22311. But finding the maximum of `c` is generally different than minimizing `a,b`. In order to answer this, you'll need to be able to write down the tradeoff that you're willing to accept between larger `c` and smaller `a,b`.

Comment: In your example, c=7 is the largest value, but a+b for the second row is also larger than a+b for the first row. So is the correct answer row 2 (because c is largest) or is the correct answer row 1 (because a + b is smallest)? And more importantly, why is the chosen row the correct answer? These are the questions you'll need to answer to be able to solve this problem.